# calling an object method with a setTimeout function from within the same object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

OBeen bangin my head against the desk with this one and I have tried the answers I find on SE. Please help.

I have a function that polls an api for new data. All I want is for the function to repeat itself every 10000 ms. I thought the following would work:

```
    //SURVIVORS_OBJECT
//Store the suvivor object and append the map markers and some additional parameters to it
var survivorMarkers;
function dz_survivorMarkers(){
    //The survivors will be stored as an 'armaMapMarker' object 
    this.survivors = {};
    //Clear a survivor from the list because by id (eg: has not been returned in our query)
    this.clearSurvivor = function(pId){
        this.survivors[pId].marker.setMap(null);
        delete this.survivors[pId];
    };
    //make the api request from the overwatch data api
    this.getSurvivorsRequest = function(){
        console.log('UDBG:::survivorMarkers.getSurvivors ENTERED');
        //the callback function is passed as well
        api.getSurvivors(this.setSurvivors)
    };
    //Set survivors
    //This is the big one - here we will loop through all our existing survivors and check
    //  if they have been returned in the new reponse. If so, we will update their position on
    //  the map and add a poly line from their last position to their new one
    //We will also check if their info window is open, and will open it again for the user
    //The detail window will be checked if it is open too, and it's contents will be refreshed
    this.setSurvivors = function(pResponse) {
        console.log('UDBG:::survivorMarkers.setSurvivors ENTERED');
        console.log(pResponse);
//          try {
            if(pResponse.errors.length > 0) {
                exceptionHandler.e('SRV100',pResponse.errors.message);  
            } else {
                //First go through all our existing survivors, and see if they are in this request too
                var newSurvivors = {};
                for(var id in pResponse.records) {
                    //console.log('UDBG:::survivorMarkers.setSurvivors looping through survivor[' + id + ']');
                    var newSurvivor = new armaMapMarker('SURVIVOR', pResponse.records[id]);

                    //check if this record is in our existing list of survivors
                    if(this.survivors != null && this.survivors[id] != null) {
                        //set our interface options if any
                        newSurvivor.detailWindowIsOpen = this.survivors[id].detailWindowIsOpen;
                        newSurvivor.infoWindowIsOpen = this.survivors[id].infoWindowIsOpen;
                        //And clear the old data
                        this.clearSurvivor(id);
                    }
                    newSurvivors[id] = newSurvivor;
                }
                //Now go through all our old survivors, and see if they were NOT in the response and can be removed
                for(var id in this.survivors) {
                    if(pResponse.records[id] == null) {
                        this.clearSurvivor(id);
                    }
                }
                this.survivors = newSurvivors;
            }
//          } catch (e) {
//              alert(e);   
//          }
        setInterval(function(){survivorMarkers.getSurvivorsRequest()},5000);
    }
}
```

It will run once, but the second time will get an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'clearSurvivor'
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is answered somewhere, I swear I've tried about 7 different answers on SO and they aren't working for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowhere is `survivorMarkers` defined, only declared. If you mean to call on the new instance, you will need to do something along the following lines. You also will want to change the `setInterval` to `setTimeout` as otherwise, you would be generating a new interval upon each API call completion, rather than generating a single new request upon the completion of a prior one. Hence we have the following.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    this.getSurvivorsRequest();
}.bind(this), 5000);
```

Or perhaps:

```
var thiz = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    thiz.getSurvivorsRequest();
}, 5000);
```

Lastly, your passed callback, `this.setSurvivors` is not bound to the instance and so is instead called on the global, fix this with `api.getSurvivors(this.setSurvivors.bind(this))`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I should have mentioned that the object was instantiated somewhere else 'survivorMarkers = new dz_survivorMarkers()'.  I attempted both of your suggestions and now I am getting a similar exception: 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method getSurvivorsRequest'

Comment: @Jay-NicolasHackleman Read my edit, that's where your issue with `[object global]` lies.

Comment: thanks @matt3141 - The bind function is new to me. I will have to learn more about it.

Comment: @Jay-NicolasHackleman The idea is that when you pass `this.setSurvivors` the function's value is passed as a callback, but now it will be orphaned, not called on the instance, and so by binding you "bind" to it the context (`this` value) of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `this.getSurvivorsRequest()` not `survivorMarkers` that is the object instance you created.